# Python 'No JSON object could be decoded' possible encoding error

Tags: python, json, character-encoding, ironpython

I'm running a custom script and having trouble writing/reading to a json file.
It worked a couple of weeks ago but suddenly it doesn't work anymore and I'm not sure why.
I used `with open()` before and now changed it to `io.open()` to force the **encoding** but no luck..

```
try:
    t_name= None
    if os.path.isdir(directory) and path.isfile(filepath):

        t_name= EXEC_PARAMS.event_args.GetTransactionNames()[0]
        if t_name!= None:

            with io.open(filepath, "r", encoding='utf8') as json_in:

                myObject = json_in.read()
                u = myObject.decode('utf-8-sig')
                myObject = u.encode('utf-8')
                print(json_in.encoding)

                data = json.load(json_in)
                if t_namein data.keys():
                    data[t_name] += 1
                else:
                    data[t_name] = 1

            with io.open(filepath, 'wb', encoding='utf8') as json_out:
                json.dump(data, json_out, ensure_ascii=False)

except Exception, e:
    print(e.message)
    pass
```

**The OUTPUT is:**

```
utf8 
No JSON object could be decoded
```

Any idea what is wrong here?

**EDIT:**

The error is in the json.load() line.

```
Script Executor Traceback:
IronPython.Runtime.Exceptions.ValueErrorException: No JSON object could be decoded
 at Microsoft.Scripting.Interpreter.ThrowInstruction.Run(InterpretedFrame frame)
 at Microsoft.Scripting.Interpreter.Interpreter.HandleException(InterpretedFrame frame, Exception exception)
 at Microsoft.Scripting.Interpreter.Interpreter.Run(InterpretedFrame frame)
 at Microsoft.Scripting.Interpreter.LightLambda.Run2[T0,T1,TRet](T0 arg0, T1 arg1)
 at IronPython.Compiler.PythonScriptCode.RunWorker(CodeContext ctx)
 at PyRevitLabs.PyRevit.Runtime.IronPythonEngine.Execute(ScriptRuntime& runtime)
```

Comment: What is the name of the file and its content?

Comment: Hi, the name is "LOG History.json" and it's just an empty json.
It should be created if it doesn't exist in any case..

Comment: The json module does not allow empty data. The displayed error is normal when trying to read an empty file.

Comment: It also didn't work when the file wasn't empty.. I placed this in the file and ran it again, no change: 
{
  "test": 123
}

Comment: Hmm..., it should not have raised the same error... unless the current directory is not what you expect and the file has not been found.

Comment: what is also weird is that if I add a print() statement just after the else: then it doesn't print, but the print() statement before the data= line does. Could this be connected? I'm not sure where the error stems from in all this... the file and path and code seem fine..

Comment: Run without `try..except` and analyse full error traceback…

Comment: @JosefZ added an EDIT in the original post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this line you read the file, advancing the file pointer to the end of the file:

```
myObject = json_in.read()
```

then in this line, you read the file again

```
data = json.load(json_in)
```

but now the file pointer is at the end of the file, so there is no data to be read, and so Python reports that `No JSON object could be decoded`.

If you want to read the file twice, you need to reset the file pointer to the beginning of the file before the second attempt at reading, like this:

```
json_in.seek(0)
```

However in the code in the question a second read doesn't seem necessary; instead you could remove the second read and load the data from `myObject`:

```
myObject = json_in.read()
u = myObject.decode('utf-8-sig')
myObject = u.encode('utf-8')
print(json_in.encoding)

# Load the data we have already read
data = json.loads(myObject)

if t_namein data.keys():
    data[t_name] += 1
else:
    data[t_name] = 1
```

Or load the json directly from the file, skipping the unnecessary decoding attempts (the data from a file opened in mode 'r' will be a `unicode` instance).

```
with io.open(filepath, "r", encoding='utf8') as json_in:

    data = json.load(json_in)
    if t_namein data.keys():
        data[t_name] += 1
    else:
        data[t_name] = 1
```

Comment: thank you. The whole myObject sequence was just to see the encoding, so I removed it now and tried the `encoding='utf8'` like you suggest, but I get `binary mode doesn't take an encoding argument`. That's why I tried the myObject stuff in the firstplace.. Something isn't right with the encoding.

Comment: You seem to be writing the output  file in binary mode (`"wb"`) but also specifying an encoding.  Instead write it in text mode (`"w"`) and specify the encoding:  `with io.open(filepath, 'w', encoding='utf8') as json_out:`

Comment: Besides having the 'wb' changed, which solved the issue, @Serge Ballesta was also right to indicate that the file cannot be an empty json. Thanks guys!